# pandas datetime import unsupported opperand

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with this line of code.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime    
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: (datetime.now() - x['Date']).days, axis=1)
```

It is working on a computer using pandas V.12 but not a computer using V.13.
Is it v.13 or something else?

output:
'Traceback (most recent call last):
 ....
 Attribute Error: ("'module' object has not attribute 'now'", u'occured at index 0')

Comment: You may need to provide some more context. The traceback indicates that on one machine you are doing `import datetime` and on the other you're doing `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: You are right, it appears to be datetime that is the problem.  i can't even make example code.  this fails     d = {   'case' : pd.Series([2., 2.]),
      'date' : pd.Series([datetime(2012, 5, 2), datetime(2012, 5, 2)])}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datetime.now()
```

is only possible if you used

```
from datetime import datetime
```

If you used

```
import datetime
```

then it should read

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

`datetime` is the name of the module as well as the name of a class in that module.

Your line

```
import datetime as datetime
```

is exactly the same as

```
import datetime
```

This probably has nothing to do with pandas (at least not the version), but see @DSM's comment. So you probably did not execute exactly the same on both machines.

Comment: Another possibility is that the OP did `from pandas import *` in one case in the code he isn't showing (`pandas.datetime` is `datetime.datetime`).

Comment: I understand. I'm new!  i think at some point i had (from datetime import datetime.now) and (import datetime as datetime) and deleted one to clean up.  thanks!

Comment: @ChetMeinzer If the code in the question is the exact code executed on both computers, I cannot see how any of them could run without error. You have to change `import datetime as datetime` to `from datetime import datetime`.